# maven plugin - get generated-sources directory

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am developing a Maven plugin. Is there a way to get the location of the `target\generated-sources` directory? It is possible to get the location of the `target` directory as following:

```
@Mojo(...)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}", readonly = true)
    private File target;

    ....
```

This gives:

```
<base dir>\target
```

I need:

```
<base dir>\target\generated-sources
```

Ofcourse, I can append `generated-sources` to the path, but it is probably better to rely on the project settings.

So this is not desired:

```
@Mojo(...)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}\generated-sources", readonly = true)
    private File target;

    ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the following in your mojo:

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/WhatEver", required=true)
private File targetFolder;
```

If you set required you are able to change it via pom file configuration. If you set is `readonly` you can't change it in the pom file.

For the `generated-sources` part there does not exist an special place holder etc. So in other words there is no other way to go.

Comment: Thanks. If there is no special place holder, how does the Maven processor know that `generated-sources/` and `generated-sources/WhatEver` in particular should be included during the compilation process?

Comment: Added supplemental answer. What Maven processor?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you can add source directories!

Answer (score 4):

If you need to add the folder to the compilation process you have to go this way:

```java
@Parameter (defaultValue="${project}", required=true, readonly=true)
private MavenProject project;
...

project.addCompileSourceRoot(TheFolderYouWouldLikeToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "target/generated-sources" is not a standard folder for generated sources.
2. Any plugin which generate sources, "asks" where to generate the sources. E.g. for jaxws:wsimport, it is parameter "sourceDestDir".